# Where to hold tabulated info to be used by objects that will be constructed and destructed frequently in C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement my own pairwise (protein/dna/rna) alignment code. For proteins, there are tables of scores for each pairing of two letters. Imagine a 20 by 20 matrix, where indices are one of 20 letters. For instance, `(C,C)` corresponds to `9`, and so on. I figured I'd set up an `unordered_map` for each possible pair (either as concatenated chars, or tuples), and once it's set up, the lookups are `O(1)`. However, I'm unclear as to where and when to create this map.

I have a `PairwiseAligner` class that looks like this:

```
class PairwiseAligner{
    std::string algorithm = "needleman_wunsch";
    std::string query_sequence;
    std::string target_sequence;

    int gap_penalty;
    int score;

    int **F;
    direction **pointers;
public:
    PairwiseAligner(){};
    void set_algorithm(std::string alg) {algorithm = alg;}
    std::string get_algorithm() {return algorithm;}
    void set_query(std::string query_) {query = query_;}
    std::string get_query(){return query;}
    void set_target(std::string target_) {target = target_;}
    std::string get_target(){return target;}

    void align(){
        if (query.size() == 0 || target.size() == 0) throw "query or target not set";

        const int n = query.size() + 1;
        const int m = target.size() + 1;

        // allocate memory for F and pointers
        F = new int*[n];
        for (auto t : F){
            new int[m];
        }

        pointers = new direction*[n];
        for (auto t : pointers){
            new direction[m];
        }

        if (algorithm.compare("needleman_wunsch")==0) needleman_wunsch();
    }

    void needleman_wunsch(){
        ... run algorithm ...
    }

    ~PairwiseAligner(){
        for (auto t : F){
            delete t;
        }
        delete F;

        for (auto t : pointers){
            delete t;
        }
        delete pointers;
    }
};
```

I need to be able to look up pairs `N^2` times within `PairwiseAligner::needleman_wunsch`. I also will be creating and destroying this object for each pair of sequences. The number of such pairs can reach 1 or 2 million.

Do I:

1. Have the unordered_map in a separate `.hpp` file and include it (and thus have global variables)?
2. Find a way to recycle the created `PairwiseAligner` objects for each alignment? (Which requires deallocating and reallocating mem for the pointers to 2d arrays `F` and `pointers` as sequences (and thus their sizes) change?
3. Something else?

Comment: `int **F; direction **pointers;` -- You should be using `std::vector` here.  Your current code has multiple errors, mostly due to using raw pointers and dynamically allocated memory incorrectly.  Using `std::vector` alleviates those issues.

Comment: `PairwiseAligner(){};` -- This simple program has issues:  `int main() { PairwiseAligner p; }` -- the reason is that the default constructor did not initialize the pointer members.  Thus when the destructor is called, undefined behavior occurs.  [Here is a cleaned up version of your code](https://godbolt.org/z/hbn6en5E8).

Comment: Listen to @paul.  Write C++, not C.

Comment: @PaulSanders that's fair, ty.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thanks. So would you suggest putting the unordered map within the class, and re-use the object repeatedly?

Comment: "where and when to create this map" depends entirely upon "where and when" the map is to be used, and how. Describing, in detail, what the map contains offers very little guidance as to "where and when to create this map", just like describing, in detail, all the sights and sounds between one's street and the nearest airport helps in deciding where and when wants to go on vacation.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik poetic.